# Get "n" number of bits from "m" number of bytes

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, bit-fields

I have a problem with extracting specific amount of bits from specific bytes.
Lets say we have case like:

(I assume that I start counting bytes/bits from 0)
I receive 3 bytes from stream and want to read 11 bits starting from 1st byte's 7th bit : finishing at 2nd byte's 5nd bit, and I want to store it somewhere

Some visualisation:

```
     0th byte          1st byte         2nd byte
|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|#|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|#|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|
                   ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^   ^ ^ ^
```

I know that bit shifting is a direction to go, but I lack experience in that topic, and Im really curious on the opinion from experienced developers

EDIT:
Sorry for not specifying it before - the language is C++, but I cannot use libraries like "bitset".

The "n" and "m" can be any number, eg.:
n = 17
m = 5. Another assumption is that data will need to be continous - it means that in the end I need to have e.g. 11 bits of continous data.

What I was trying to do was something like this:

```
buf[0] << ((byteCount - 1) - index) * stepWidth;
```

Which gave me full first/second byte. In the end readed bits should be "merged" as one variable, somehing like:

```
int buf[1] = variable with 8 bits;
int buf[2] = variable with 3 bits;
mergedBuf  = buf[1] + buf[1] // "+" means merging, not adding values
```

Comment: what problem do you have? What did you try? C or C++ ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre] of *your own* attempt, and [edit] your question to show it together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: At this moment, the question is not clear. If you want an algorithm to calculate bits of each byte, then search it on internet.

Comment: `bytes[1]` and `(bytes[2]>>5)&7` or what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Portable ISO C doesn't guarantee the existence of a type for an 8-bit byte.  (Although if `uint8_t` exists on an implementation, it's a byte.)  You could `static_assert(sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(uint8_t))` or something, although that's probably redundant; I don't think it's possible for that to be different.  Or do you want something that will still extract the same bits from a sequence of memory even if run on a word-addressable machine with CHAR_BIT==32?  Then you'll have to be careful with `memcpy` into `unsigned` or `uint32_t` chunks before shifting.

Comment: Are there special constraints on n and m ? In particular, do you need to handle n>32 or even n>64 ? Currently you'd just `memcpy` the last 2 bytes to an `unsigned long` and shift it right by the 5 bits you don't want.

Comment: How to do it kind of depends on what that data is. Is it an 11 bit number for example, or is it just raw bits? In case it's a number, then where is the MSB? Is it little or big endian?

Answer (score 2):

C++ has nice class in standart library:

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

If C is the case, you can use bit mask and & (and) operation. like:

```
unsigned char buf[3]; // let's say this is your buffer;
int _2nd_byte_value = buf[1] & 0xFF; // since you want to get all bits of 2nd byte;
int _3rd_byte_value = (buf[2] & 0xE0) >> 5; // first mask then shift;
```

Then you can manipulate these values as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will try to come up with something based on your suggestion